# Getting trading data efficiently

Tags: nft, erc-721, erc-1155, graphs

How can I get historical trading data of an NFT collection programmatically? If it's a third party that can provide a service, please let me know and which one's are best too!

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This data is not available readily on-chain, so it becomes difficult to get this kind of data.

[QuickNode](https://www.quicknode.com/graph-api) has this data available via their Graph API

You get historical NFT Trading data, marketplace metadata, price data, multiple NFT image sizes, and more via a flexible GraphQL interface.

To get NFT Trading data use a query like this

```
query Query($contractAddress: String!, $tokenId: String!) {
  ethereum {
    nft(contractAddress: $contractAddress, tokenId: $tokenId) {
      collection {
        orderHistory {
          fromAddress
          priceInNativeToken
          timestamp
          transactionHash
        }
        sales {
          edges {
            node {
              priceInNativeToken
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With the following as variables:

```
{
  "contractAddress": "contract_address_goes_here",
  "tokenId": "token_id_of_nft"
}
```